# Querying array of events to find if the event I'm adding is overlapping (Express/Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongo db with a document collection where each element has a busy array that collects events. The mongoose model is as follows:

```
busy: [{
      _id : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      isBusy : Boolean,
      eventType : String,
      title : String,
      startDate : Date,
      endDate : Date,
      event: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event', index: true },
    }],
```

As this gets populated I want to query all the documents where in the array there are no events that are happening at the same time of the event I'm trying to add, so I can choose only documents that are not busy in that moment.

The query I'm using is

```
{
  "user.busy": {
    $not: {
      $elemMatch: {
        'startDate': {
          $gte: startDate,
          $lt: endDate
        },
        'endDate': {
          $gte: startDate,
          $lt: endDate
        },
        isBusy: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And it's not working.
Any hint on how I should proceed to do this?

**--- sample data**

This is an example of a busy array from my db

```
"busy" : [ 
            {
                "isBusy" : true,
                "eventType" : "Shooting",
                "title" : "Shooting",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2018-08-23T00:00:28.000Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-08-23T03:00:28.000Z"),
                "event" : ObjectId("5b5573fcba399fababcb200d")
            }, 
            {
                "isBusy" : true,
                "eventType" : "Shooting",
                "title" : "Shooting",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2018-08-23T06:30:28.000Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-08-23T09:30:28.000Z"),
                "event" : ObjectId("5b557410ba399fababcb2013")
            }, 
            {
                "isBusy" : true,
                "eventType" : "Shooting",
                "title" : "Shooting",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2018-08-23T10:11:06.000Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-08-23T13:11:06.000Z"),
                "event" : ObjectId("5b5580216a5615aca0d089e0")
            }, 
            ],
```

**-- edit 1**

Since the query works when it's done raw on the database it's probably something in my Mongoose implementation, done as follows

```
Element.find({ 
 "user.busy" : 
   { $not : 
     { $elemMatch : 
       {
         'startDate' : { $gte: startDate, $lt: endDate }, 
         'endDate' : { $gte: startDate, $lt: endDate }, 
         isBusy : true 
       } 
     } 
   } 
 })
.exec()
.then(...)
```

Comment: please post your sample document and the output

Comment: Can you explain what scenario is not working ? Why do you have isBusy flag in the query ?

Comment: the isBusy flag is because users can use the same fields to create other kind of events in the calendar that do not qualify them as busy for the system

Comment: i tried to remove the isBusy: true but nothing changes. The only case that seems to work is when i try to create an event that is a duplicate (same startDate/endDate). Another thing that should be noted is that dates include time

Comment: Why `user.busy` ? try accessing the array directly i.e `busy`

Comment: user.busy because i query the busy field of a "user" subdocument

Answer (score 1):

Input:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6495b4611de4551f5eb8d4"),
    "user" : {
        "busy" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b6493b5611de4551f5eb878"),
                "isBusy" : true,
                "eventType" : "Shooting",
                "title" : "Shooting",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2018-01-23T00:00:28.000Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-08-23T03:00:28.000Z"),
                "event" : ObjectId("5b5573fcba399fababcb200d")
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b649486611de4551f5eb89f"),
                "isBusy" : true,
                "eventType" : "Shooting",
                "title" : "Shooting",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2018-08-23T10:11:06.000Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2018-10-23T13:11:06.000Z"),
                "event" : ObjectId("5b5580216a5615aca0d089e0")
            }
        ]
    }
}    
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6495e5611de4551f5eb8df"),
    "user" : {
        "busy" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b6493b5611de4551f5eb878"),
                "isBusy" : true,
                "eventType" : "Playing Games",
                "title" : "MORTAL KOMBAT",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2017-04-23T00:00:28.000Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2017-06-23T03:00:28.000Z"),
                "event" : ObjectId("5b5573fcba399fababcb200d")
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b6493bf611de4551f5eb87a"),
                "isBusy" : true,
                "eventType" : "Coding",
                "title" : "JavaScript",
                "startDate" : ISODate("2017-07-23T06:30:28.000Z"),
                "endDate" : ISODate("2017-08-23T09:30:28.000Z"),
                "event" : ObjectId("5b557410ba399fababcb2013")
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

General rule of thumb with `$not` is to create a query that you know it works and use `$not` to negate it. 
So you have `find me x, and then everything not equal (and not existing as well) to x`. So lets create the `find me x`:

```
var startDate = ISODate("2017-11-23T00:00:28.000Z"),
    endDate = ISODate("2018-09-23T03:00:28.000Z")

db.getCollection('busy').find({
  "user.busy": {
      $elemMatch: {          
        'startDate': {
            $gte: startDate,
            $lt: endDate
        },          
        'endDate': {
            $gte: startDate,
            $lt: endDate
        },
        isBusy: true
      }
    }
})
```

This would return the user with `_id : ObjectId("5b6495b4611de4551f5eb8d4")` which is the correct result if you look closely at the dates and the 2 date ranges provided with the code. That user `is busy` during the period of 2017-11-23 and 2018-09-23 since he does have a `Shooting` event 2018-01-23 to 2018-08-23 (`"_id" : ObjectId("5b6493b5611de4551f5eb878")`). So far so good. Now lets add the `$not`:

```
db.getCollection('busy').find({
  "user.busy": {
    $not: {
      $elemMatch: {          
        'startDate': {
            $gte: startDate,
            $lt: endDate
        },          
        'endDate': {
            $gte: startDate,
            $lt: endDate
        },
        isBusy: true
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Result is user `"_id" : ObjectId("5b6495e5611de4551f5eb8df")`. That is again the correct result since that user has no events during the date range of 2017-11-23 and 2018-09-23.

Conclusion ... your query works! :)

Comment: Did you try it raw on mongo? I was thinking that maybe it could be a problem with some operator in Mongoose or with something else. Because it does not work in my implementation...

Comment: I test it in Mongo/Robo 3T console.

Comment: This has probably something to do with with mongoose, I'm adding info on the main post.

Comment: Did you try to see if it works by just using `$elemMatch` without the `$not`? To make sure that at least that returns the documents you expect.

Comment: @soulpaul so I ended up doing a small app for this with just one model etc. Using mongoose everything works as expected. For sample data I used the 2 models I posted above since it is `very` clear when one is available and when not based on the dates passed. I used the same dates as I posed above as range to test with.